# Visual Studio Enterprise 17.8 - Intellitest Preview Feature

Tags: visual-studio, intellitest

The release of Visual Studio 17.8 should contain a preview feature, named '[Intellitest](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-17-8-now-available/#testing)'.
I've installed Visual Studio 17.8 Enterprise, but the feature is missing in the 'Manage Preview Features' dialog (even when I open Visual Studio without a project/ solution). Do I need to install an additional component?

Comment: I can't see the option either in preview features either! Right-clicking in a method though shows the IntelliTest context menu option though. Maybe it's been shipped!